# What is the Doctor's real name?

Tags: doctor-who

Is there anywhere (in canon) where the Doctor's real name is ever revealed? I know that several people do know it or learn it at some point (like the Master, River, and Clara for example), but is it ever revealed to us?

Comment: Nope... Absolutely nowhere is it actually revealed... The Doctor has joked around it, but nothing solid.

Comment: Doctor's true name is Bob

Comment: @Petersaber Nah, it's Mildred!

Comment: To answer to a merged question :
John Hurt is not the Doctor's name at all. Sir John Hurt is the actor who's playing the War Doctor.
So the "Introducing John Hurt as The Doctor" is nothing more than a presentation.

Comment: Did you notice how the show is called "Doctor Who?"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Doctor *Who*"

Comment: @Ben What.....?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is it a title, or a question? ;)

Comment: @Ben: It is a title. I was asking a question

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Doctor *Who?*" is a running joke in the series.  It is not The Doctor's name. Suggesting that his name is "Who" makes as much sense as positing that either Angela or Tony's real name was "Who" in the show "Who's The Boss?"

Comment: @PaulL: Yes, I know. I didn't mean to suggest that his name is "Who". What I am pointing out is, well, pretty much exactly what you just said. The show is called "Doctor Who" -> we don't know his name, and we won't know his name, so this SE question is vacuous!

Comment: Capaldi's Doctor says his name is Basil, but you know... the Doctor lies!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### **The Doctor's name is unknown.**

The true name of Doctor Who is one of the great mysteries of the series (e.g. see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/30698/31394)).

Steven Moffat, the executive producer, has [said](http://www.nme.com/filmandtv/news/doctor-who-s-real-name-is-mildred-claims-steven-mo/342048) the Doctor's real name is **Mildred**, but this is generally assumed to be a joke. (Rule #0: the Moffat lies.) In Series 9, the Doctor tells Osgood that his first name is **Basil**, but this is presumably also a joke. (Rule #1: the Doctor lies.)

In Series 10, it is claimed that his real name is **Doctor Who**:

> BILL: So, why do you keep calling yourself Doctor Who?
>  MISSY: Because I'm pretending to be him. Because that's the whole point of this ridiculous exercise.
>  [...]
>  BILL: Yeah, but he's called the Doctor, so
>  MISSY: He says, I'm the Doctor, and they say, Doctor who? See, I'm cutting to the chase, baby. I'm streamlining. I'm saving us actual minutes.
>  BILL: Yeah, okay, whatever.
>  MISSY: Also it's his real name.
>  [...]
>  BILL: Sorry, what do you mean, it's his real name? Nobody knows the Doctor's real name.
>  MISSY: I do, because I grew up with him, and his real name is Doctor Who.
>  DOCTOR: Bill, she's just trying to wind you up.
>  MISSY: Chose it himself, you know, trying to sound mysterious. And then he dropped the Who when he realised it was a tiny bit on the nose.
>
>  <sub>-- S10E11 (World Enough and Time)</sub>

Again, I would assume that this isn't actually true. (Rule #2: the Master lies.) If the Doctor's name really is such an earth-shattering secret as it was made out to be in Series 6, then it would hardly be the thing everyone says as soon as they meet him. Nor would the question broadcast from Trenzalore in "The Time of the Doctor" make sense if that question was actually his real name.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of merging your answer over to this (in my mind,  superior) question.

Comment: @Richard I was wondering how rand al'thor was able to answer the question 22 days before it was asked!

Comment: @n.soong - He's a witch! BURN HIM!!

Comment: @Richard I think it'd be more appropriate to declare him as a timelord... considering the context :P

Comment: @Ben New question: *Is Rand al'Thor a Time Lord?* :-D

Comment: @randal'thor - I thought we'd established that you're a witch.

Comment: Although, I bumped you up on this, I'm pretty sure his name isn't unknown, and it isn't nobody either, although he has played cowboy before...

Answer (score 1):

While we may not know his actual name, we do know he went by Theta Sigma while at the Time Lord Academy on Gallifrey and it is the answer to the question, Doctor Who? That must never be answered.

Some have suggested that maybe Theta Sigma is his name or short for what his name really is. I don't believe we will ever get the answer to that. However, it has been said that only children can hear his name. But that doesn't necessarily mean they can understand his name.

See “The Armageddon Factor” and “Happiness Patrol” on the name Theta Sigma. Drax called him Theet. Short for Theta Sigma.

> Come on, Theet. Class of ninety two?
>
> Yeah. We was on the tech course together. Long time ago now, Theet, eh? Must be what, four hundred and fifty years? And a long way from Gallifrey.
>
> <sub>The Armageddon Factor, Part Six.</sub>

Comment: Are you sure that Theta Sigma wasn't his fraternity name?

Comment: I mean I guess it's possible however there is a Time Lord that calls him Theta Sigma, see The Armageddon Factor. Also in Happiness Patrol the name came up again.