# In what 12th Doctor episode does he say his name?

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

I seem to remember the 12th Doctor telling his name (it might have just been his last name) to a character in one episode, about halfway through his run. I'm inclined to think it was "Bazel", although I may be wrong.

Is there actually a 12th Doctor episode where he says his name (and we, the viewers hear it)?

I am looking for the episode (or its lack of existence), not the name itself; there's already [a question asking about the name](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93570/what-is-the-doctors-real-name).

Comment: The Doctor's real name is a running joke that has been going on for over 50 years. It has never been said and I'm pretty sure it never will.

Comment: Does Who ever actually say his name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scene you're thinking of is in series 9 episode 8, [The Zygon Inversion](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/35-8.html).

> DOCTOR: What's your name?
>
> OSGOOD: Osgood.
>
> DOCTOR: No, no, no. Your first name?
>
> OSGOOD: What's your first name?
>
> DOCTOR: Basil.
>
> OSGOOD: Petronella.
>
> DOCTOR: Let's just, er, stick with what we had.

This is almost certainly a joke, however, like the other instance in the question you linked.

Note: the American pronunciation of the word "basil" has a long A sound, but the British has a short A sound. That's why you're remembering "Bazel".

Comment: They're detectives.

https://twitter.com/VBartilucci/status/663253008055181312